# Data transfer JAVA ->C# - clarification?

Tags: java, c#, tcp

I'm building an android application (with java 1.6) -  which is the actual client

It sends and receives data to a windows machine which hosts .net application which uses `networkStream` and `socket TCP/IP`.

The data which is sent is `bytes` ( obviously - all is bytes) but the types that the java client convert to bytes are :

`ints`, `Guids` , `string` ( bytes are via utf 8 encoding).

**Question**

I believe that primitive types can safely be - decoded at the .net side.

For example :  if I send 4 bytes at the java side - I can get the int back in the C# side :

```
 public static int ConvertBytesToInt(byte[] LengthValueBytes)
        {
            var bitArray = new BitArray(LengthValueBytes);
            if (bitArray.Length > 32)
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument length shall be at most 32 bits.");
            int[] array = new int[1];
            bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
            return array[0];
        }
```

Also strings :

`Encoding.UTF8.GetString(...bytes....)`

But what about more complex types ? GUIDs  ,DateTimes  etc... ?

Am I only safe on the primitive side ?

Comment: Define "safe". What specific problem are you trying to solve here? You obviously can't reconstitute Java-only types in .NET code or vice a versa, so of course there's a limit to what you can accomplish. But you can _always_ write some code to explicitly interpret the bytes you receive.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I didnt expect a serialized `person` class to be deserialized on the .net side. Im just asking on which types I'm totally safe ( int as I said , string as i also said) --in short am i only safe in the primitive types ?

Comment: You will need to convert everything to bytes.  How Java holds a DateTime may not be compatible with how .NET holds dates.  If you pass the millseconds or something streamed a bytes, then that should work.

Comment: @ScaryWombat So is it only legit for the primitives ? ( what about bool) ? i've heard that java optimize how he keeps bools.... ( im not that familiar with java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be pretty careful, as you can get caught by issues such as byte order, word sizes, different internal representations, etc.

You might want to consider using a standardised interchange format such as JSON, BSON, XML or ASN1.1. .NET and Java have classes or libraries for all of these formats which should help you to avoid all of the common pitfalls.

If you are determined to do it youself, it should be feasible.

BitConverter in .NET helps you to avoid endianness issues. Java is always in network byte order (big-endian).

Dates and Times have different internal representations. It may me easier to transmit it as a string in RFC1123 format (or similar). DateTime in .NET has an internal unit of a Tick (100 nanosecond). Date in Java uses 1 millisecond as its internal unit.

Both java.util.UUID and System.Guid have constructors which should allow you to convert between the types fairly easily.